# extracting an object from a array of objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I have a array of objects of interface `Subjects`. I want only a single object from that array and pass it as a prop to a component to render that data. "I am new To Typescript".

```js
export interface Subjects {
  id: number;
  subject: string;
  subjectName: string;
  periods: number[];
  faculty: string;
  slot: string;
  code: string;
  googleClassRoomLink?: string;
  googleMeetLink?: string;
}

export const Main: React.FC = () => {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<Subjects[]>(s4);
  const [currentPeriod, setCurrentPeriod] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [subjectInfo, setSubjectInfo] = useState<Subject | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = allData.filter((item) => item.subject === currentPeriod);
    setSubjectInfo(data);
  }, [currentPeriod]);

  return (
    <div className="Main">
      <Table subjects={allData} setCurrentPeriod={setCurrentPeriod} />
      {currentPeriod && subjectInfo && (
        <DisplayInfo subjectsInfo={subjectInfo} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the second component

```js
import { Subjects } from './Main';
interface Props {
  subjectsInfo: Subjects;
}

export const DisplayInfo: React.FC<any> = ({ subjectsInfo }) => {
  console.log(subjectsInfo);

  return (
    <div className="DisplayInfo">
        <div>
          <h3>{subjectsInfo.subjectName}</h3>
          <h4>{subjectsInfo.subject}</h4>
          <h4>{subjectsInfo.faculty}</h4>
          <h4>{subjectsInfo.slot}</h4>
          <h4>{subjectsInfo.code}</h4>

          <button>ClassRoom</button>
          <button>Meet</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now typescript says i cant do it
`Argument of type 'Subjects[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Subjects | null>'. Type 'Subjects[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Subjects | null) => Subjects | null'. Type 'Subjects[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Subjects | null): Subjects | null'.`

Comment: In this line: `const [allData, setAllData] = useState<Subjects[]>(s4);` what is s4?

Comment: Also, in this line `const [subjectInfo, setSubjectInfo] = useState<Subject | null>(null);` are you defining an interface for `Subject` somewhere, or is that a misspelling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Your `allData` is an array of object `Subjects[]`, after you apply a filter to it `allData.filter` your `data` is sill an array**

Because [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=vi) return an array not a single item.

So when you set back your `data` to `setSubjectInfo(data)` it missmatch type with `Subject | null` type.

**If you want to have only the first found item of your array, try [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:**

```
const data = allData.find((item) => item.subject === currentPeriod);
setSubjectInfo(data);
```

**But [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) return an item | `undefined` so you would need to change your useState type to:**

```
const [subjectInfo, setSubjectInfo] = useState<Subject | undefined>();
```

Comment: This works but is this the only way we can do in type script

Comment: I updated the answer, you can use Array.find instead.

Comment: Is there any other function like filter that returns the first object that satisfies the condition

Comment: Yeah, check if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code is correct. The only part you need to modify is the filter part. When you filter an array[] based on a condition, it return an array. So if you're sure that every subject is unique, then return 0th index of filtered array that will be of type Subjects.

That way data will be of type Subjects | null as specified in your state.

```
    const data = allData.filter((item) => item.subject === currentPeriod)[0];
```